# @PersistenceContext EntityManager thread-safety in Spring and Java EE

Tags: spring, thread-safety, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, entitymanager

`EntityManager` is **not thread-safe** by definition.
Servlets specs says that in non-distributed environment and without implementing `SingleThreadModel`, there is **only one servlet instance per definition**.

Therefore, in Java EE when you inject an `EntityManager` through the `@PersistenceContext` into Servlet's field - it's not thread safe:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // Not thread-safe, should be using EMF instead.
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

1. Is this correct to say that even though the default scope of Spring beans is singleton, the `EntityManager` is thread-safe as the Spring uses `ThreadLocal` to bind its transaction and `EntityManager` to it?
2. Is the above Servlets example still valid in Spring? Is it still not thread-safe?
3. Does the `ThreadLocal` approach works only for Spring managed beans and plain servlet is not one of those?
4. As far as I remember, it's the container responsibility to inject the `EntityManager`. In Glassfish Java EE implementation, it was the application server who discovers the `@PersistenceContext` as injection point.
   How does it look like in Spring? Is the Spring Framework responsible for discovering those annotations or it's responsibility of the JPA implementor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Question 2, 3, and 4  -- Spring does not pay attention to any class that is not a Spring Bean. Therefor Spring does not pay attention to you `MyServlet` class.
Therefore the answer for

- 2) is no
- 3) only Spring managed Beans
- 4) it is Springs responsibility, because Spring is the Container

For Question 1). It works this way, so the usage of an Spring Injected Entity Manager is effective thread save.

Comment: Thanks Ralph. So, by saying "2) is no" you mean that it's not thread-safe because this servlet is not a Spring bean, so in fact **no injection will occur at all**? Is it possible to mark such Servlet as a Spring bean? I somehow feel that's quite uncommon, not recommended and messy idea - it's just a theoretical question to understand Spring's mechanism.

Comment: I mean it is not a Spring bean at all (that is what is the the first paragraph about), so there is no injection and `em` will be null. -- Test it, if it is not null, then something really strange goes on.  One way you can try to make it a spring bean is `@Configurable` but this requires real AspectJ and I have really no idea if this works for Servlets.